# building a registration system for sub-domains for a Joomla website

Tags: joomla, subdomain

What is the best plugin for building a registration system for sub-domains for a Joomla website??

Any help is highly appreciated?

Comment: Can you clarify the question a bit more?

Comment: app that will allow our users to choose from one of several domains and register a sub-domain from a keyword prefix of their choice that is entered into a form. it should chk if the domain with specified prefix is avialable.. f the sub-domain name is available, we take the name and email address of the user via another form and then send them a confirmation email with a validation code they must enter into another form to complete the order.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [these](http://extensions.joomla.org/index.php?option=com_mtree&task=listcats&cat_id=1790&Itemid=35) extensions to help you synchronize users and content among the db instances of your subdomains.